# Check if string1 is before string2 on the same line

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to match comment lines in a c#/sql code. `CREATE` may come before or after `/*`. They can be on the same line.

```
line6 = "  CREATE  /*  this is ACTIVE line 6"
line5 = " charlie /* CREATE  inside this is comment 5"
```

In the first case, it will be an active line; in the second, it will be a comment. I probably can do some kind of charindex, but maybe there is a simpler way

```
regex1 = /\/\*||\-\-/
if (line1 =~ regex1) then puts "Match comment___" + line6 else puts '____' end
if (line1 =~ regex1) then puts "Match comment___" + line5 else puts '____' end
```

Comment: What's your expected output exactly?

Comment: You haven't answered @Kasramvd's question. Considering you selected my answer, it appears that you want to return an array of the comment lines. If so, you should edit to say so. Once you have that array you can display the result however you like. For example, if `text` is an array of all lines and `comments` is an array of the comments, you could write: `text.each { |line| comments.include?(line) ? puts "..." : puts "..." }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the regex

```
r = /
    \/     # match forward slash
    \*     # match asterisk
    \s+    # match > 0 whitespace chars
    CREATE # match chars
    \b     # match word break (to avoid matching CREATED)
    /      # extended mode for regex def
```

you can return an array of the comment lines thus:

```
[line6, line5].select { |l| l =~ r }
  #=> [" charlie /* CREATE  inside this is comment 5"]
```